# Вызывается исключение при использовании библиотеки c++

Tags: c++, dll

у меня вызывается эта проблема Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x0000000000000000 в Prakt6.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при исполнении по адресу 0x0000000000000000.

Вот сам код

```
int main() {
std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "RU");
HINSTANCE hLib = LoadLibrary(L"mylib.dll");
if (hLib == NULL) {
    std::cout << "Ошибка загрузки библиотеки." << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

typedef int (*sum) (int, int);
sum Sum;
Sum = (sum)GetProcAddress(hLib, "Sum");
std::cout << Sum(2, 5);
FreeLibrary(hLib);
```

}

Сама ошибка где-то тут

```
Sum = (sum)GetProcAddress(hLib, "Sum");
std::cout << Sum(2, 5);
FreeLibrary(hLib);
```

Возможно проблема с библиотекой, поэтому я скину код, который изменял

pch.cpp

```
    #include "pch.h"

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int sum(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
```

}

framework.h

```
#pragma once
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int sum(int a, int b);
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN             // Исключите редко используемые компоненты из заголовков Windows
// Файлы заголовков Windows
#include <windows.h>
```

Comment: `if (hLib == NULL) {` - вот то, что библиотека загрузилась, вы проверяете, а что указатель на функцию получен - нет. Ну и название функции не соответствует фактическому.

Comment: После формирования dll часто используют https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Walker, там просто будут видны экспортируемые из dll функции.  Как уже указано, у Вас в названиях функции регистр разный.